# PlantUml: How to do a multiline display in opt condition for sequence diagram

Tags: plantuml

Im trying to do a UML diagram for a script below in PlantUML.

```
[plantuml, target=diagram-sequence, format=png] 
....
@startuml
-> A: test
opt ((Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_MICRO_GYRO) || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_PANASONIC_GYRO)  || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL)    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra)     || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI)    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI_SPI)    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL)    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI)     || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI_SPI)   || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL))    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra5)  || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra4))
<- A
end opt
@enduml
....
```

When I do this I cannot see the complete diagram.
[image: PlantUML DIAGRAM]

Does anyone know of a way to show the big opt conditon in multiple lines in the diagram?

Comment: Maybe you should try a few `\n` in the code like ` @startuml
...
opt ((Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_MICRO_GYRO) || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_PANASONIC_GYRO)  || \n (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL)    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra)     || \n ...
end opt
@enduml

Comment: ah ok , if I use \n but keep it in the same line while scripting. It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Adding newlines `\n` will break the `opt` across multiple lines in the diagram, but it will still be on one in the PlantUML text file, which can be hard to read.

To make things more readable, adding `\` at the end of the line will allow splitting text across multiple lines.

Combining `\n` with `\` allow splitting the single line across multiple lines in both the diagram *and* the file:

```
@startuml
-> A: test
opt ( \
    (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_MICRO_GYRO)       \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_PANASONIC_GYRO)\n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL)       \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra)         \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI)           \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI_SPI)       \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL)       \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI)           \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VTI_SPI)       \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_VIRTUAL))      \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra5)        \n\
    || (Exterme_DANGER_Forwith_cIES_Cobra4)        \n\
)
<- A
end opt
@enduml
```

[image]